# I saw the Gadget "Speed Test" and "Stock" in some Windows 7 books, but don't find it on Win 7?

Tags: windows-7, desktop-gadget

I saw the Gadget "Speed Test" and "Stock" in some Windows 7 books, but don't find it on Win 7?

There is a "Get more gadgets online" but they look quite 3rd party... and installing them might have some security risk?

Answer (score 1):

Speed Test is [here](http://gallery.live.com/liveItemDetail.aspx?li=09cdf70c-c140-48ee-85f1-6b5eeef421da).

Several Stock quote gadgets are available [here](http://gallery.live.com/search.aspx?q=stock%20quote). Just take your pick.

As for the risk of installing them : There's always a risk, but you can minimize that by choosing gadgets that have good reviews, which means that they have passed some tests by other users.